# How can I make and enforce a generic OneToOne relation in django?

Tags: django, generics, django-models, database-relations

I'd like the exact same thing as `django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericForeignKey`, but `OneToOne` instead of `ForeignKey`.  I thought an easy (albeit marginally inelegant) workaround was to add `unique=True` to the field in question, but that borks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `unique_together`?

Any combination of the `content_type` field and the `ID` field is a unique identifier for one object, therefore 1 to 1.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#unique-together

Comment: I'm also having the same issue. Using unique_together enforces the uniqueness of the relation in the database, but I still need to refer to it as my_foreign_key.objects.all()[0]. Is there any way to refer to it just as my_foreign_key, as a normal OneToOne field?

Comment: @duduklein You are free to set up any python methods on your class, like `@property def my_foreign_key(self) return foo` - anyways, it's standard practice to ask new questions if you can't find an answer.